# How to use IF statement in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, if-statement

This is the scenario I would like to have in my `INSERT` in a stored procedure.

Tables:

**tblRate**

- RateID (pk)
- Rate money
- Days int
- isDailyRate bit

**tblBooking**

- Totals money

In my vb app this is the statement. How would I translate this into T-SQL?

```
 if !isDaily = True then
      !Totals = (!Days * !Rate)
 else
      !Totals = !Rate
 end if
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tblBooking_Add] 
   (
    @RateID     bigint,
    @Rate       money,
    @Days       int,
    @CheckOUT   datetime
   )
AS
BEGIN
    --Below is the logic I want. I can't get the right syntax

    --Declare @myTotals as money
    --Declare @myCheckOut as DateTime

    --if (Select isDailyRate FROM tblRates WHERE (RateID = @RateID)) = True THEN
    --  set myTotals = (@Rate * @Days)
    --  set @CheckOUT   = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + @Days, '12:00') 
    --Else
    --  set myTotals = @Rate
    --  set @CheckOUT   = GETDATE()

    --End if

    INSERT INTO tblBooking(Totals, CheckOUT)
    VALUES(@myTotals, @myCheckOut); 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO tblBooking (Totals, CheckOUT)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN idDailyRate = 1 THEN @Rate * @Days 
    ELSE @rate 
  END,
  CASE 
    WHEN idDailyRate = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 
                                      DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + @Days, 
                                      '12:00')
    ELSE GETDATE()
  END
FROM tblRates 
WHERE RateID = @RateID;
```

**Or**, if they are scalar values, then you can select them into a variables and insert them instead of `INSERT ... INTO ... SELECT`.

---

### Update 1

Like this:

```
Declare @myTotals as money;
Declare @myCheckOut as DateTime;

SELECT 
  @myTotals = CASE 
                WHEN idDailyRate = 1 THEN @Rate * @Days 
                ELSE @rate 
              END,
  @myCheckOut = CASE 
                  WHEN idDailyRate = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 
                                                    DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + @Days, 
                                                    '12:00')
                  ELSE GETDATE()
                END
FROM tblRates 
WHERE RateID = @RateID;

INSERT INTO tblBooking (Totals, CheckOUT) VALUES(@myTotals, @myCheckOut );
```

But this will give you an error, if there is more than value returned from this table `tblRates` into those variables.

Comment: Sorry I'm still new in sql server programming. can you show me how to do it in scalar values?

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks @Mahmoud Gamal. I learned something new today. Thank you very much.